# 403 Forbidden Error for accessing images on google cloud bucket after transferred from one bucket to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Actually I am using google cloud bucket for image upload in my rails app. I am using paper clip for image upload. I have used bucket name "abcd-old". I uploaded some of the images through app. It was working fine. But as of now I transffered the content of "abcd-old" bucket to new bucket "abcd-new". Also set the same permission as it was for old one. But now images are broken in the app. it shows "403 forbidden error". If I upload new image that will work. But old I mean transffered images are broken. Please help me on this.

This is the error I am getting

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access denied.</Message>
  <Details>
     Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket abcd-new.
  </Details>
</Error>
```

Comment: I got the sollutions. we need to set transffered images to public read through google cloud command line interface by following command.

`**gsutil -m acl -r set public-read gs://abcd-new***`

[Click here for more details](http://tekhoow.blogspot.in/2015/12/soving-accessdenied-on-google-cloud.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can resolve this issue by command line

```
gsutil -m acl -r set public-read gs://abcd-new
```

Please go through this link for more details http://tekhoow.blogspot.in/2015/12/soving-accessdenied-on-google-cloud.html